# how to make this type of view on recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[See this view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXyD8.png)

I want to make a view like this wireframe.

Comment: https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/recyclerview-as-staggered-grid-example.html

Answer (score 0):

Just do like below:

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager gridlayout= new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
```